# How to catch Sublime Text exceptions on their Python interpreter?

Tags: python, exception, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

#### How to catch Sublime Text exceptions on their Python interpreter?

This was migrated to https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1359

I am trying to catch this exception:

```
    try:

        print( 'RUNNING' )
        sublime.active_window().run_command( "side_bar_update_sync" )
        isNotSyncedSideBarEnabled = False
        print( 'RUNNING THIS' )

    except BaseException:

        isNotSyncedSideBarEnabled = True
        print( 'RUNNING THIS ALSO' )
```

But when it is ran, it just does not catches it. Does not matter if I try it within `TypeError`, `Exception` or `BaseException` classes. This below is the full exception output.

```
reloading plugin SublimeDefaultSyntax.default_syntax
READ_PREF_ASYNC!!!!
    updateIsSyncedSideBarEnabled!!!!
RUNNING
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\User\Dropbox\Applications\SoftwareVersioning\SublimeText\sublime_plugin.py", line 538, in run_
    return self.run()
TypeError: run() missing 1 required positional argument: 'enable'
RUNNING THIS
isNotSyncedSideBarEnabled: False
```

The problem is, the python cannot catch the exception throwed by `run_command( "side_bar_update_sync" )`. The exception catching for errors like trying to call `self.view`, when there is no self passed by, are working fine. This is the full code:

```
def plugin_loaded():

    global isNotSyncedSideBarEnabled

    packageControlSettings = sublime.load_settings('Package Control.sublime-settings')
    userSettings           = sublime.load_settings('Preferences.sublime-settings')

    def updateIsSyncedSideBarEnabled():

        global isNotSyncedSideBarEnabled

        print('    updateIsSyncedSideBarEnabled!!!!')
        sublime.active_window().run_command( "reveal_in_side_bar" )

        try:

            print( 'RUNNING' )
            sublime.active_window().run_command( "side_bar_update_sync" )
            isNotSyncedSideBarEnabled = False
            print( 'RUNNING THIS' )

        except BaseException:

            isNotSyncedSideBarEnabled = True
            print( 'RUNNING THIS ALSO' )

        print( 'isNotSyncedSideBarEnabled: ' + str( isNotSyncedSideBarEnabled ) )



    def read_pref_async():

        print('READ_PREF_ASYNC!!!!')
        updateIsSyncedSideBarEnabled()


    def read_pref_package():

        print('READ_PREF_PACKAGE!!!!')
        updateIsSyncedSideBarEnabled()


    def read_pref_preferences():

        print('READ_PREF_PREFERENCES!!!!')
        updateIsSyncedSideBarEnabled()


    # read initial setting, after all packages being loaded
    sublime.set_timeout_async( read_pref_async, 1000 )

    # listen for changes
    packageControlSettings.add_on_change( "Package Control", read_pref_package )
    userSettings.add_on_change( "Preferences", read_pref_preferences )

    #print( userSettings.get( "ignored_packages" ) )
    #print( packageControlSettings.get( "installed_packages" ) )
```

This discussion may be followed by this Sublime Text Forum's thread: https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/how-to-add-remove-a-default-menu-entry-when-a-x-package-is-isnt-enabled-installed/22753?u=addons_zz

This are the lines from the file showed on the exception:

```
532 class ApplicationCommand(Command):
533     def run_(self, edit_token, args):
534         args = self.filter_args(args)
535         if args:
536             return self.run(**args)
537         else:
538             return self.run()
539
540    def run(self):
541        pass1
542
543 ... other classes
```

Comment: The stack trace is not relevant to your source code. Is it truncated? What do you have here: `sublime_plugin.py", line 538, in run_`?

Comment: The file on the stack track trace is a file shipped with sublime text [shipped file picture](http://i.imgur.com/jSIJu84.png). I will add those line contents within the main post. My code is on plugin which is ran/call things on/by that another sublime file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated on the question, it is indeed a bug on Sublime Text. Here's a smaller repro from the bug report:

```
import sublime_plugin

class TestCommandCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        try:
            ret = self.view.window().run_command("toggle_comment", {"comment": "no"})
        except:
            print("an exception")
        else:
            print(ret)
```

Console:

```
reloading plugin User.test
command: test_command
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_plugin.py", line 792, in run_
    return self.run(edit, **args)
TypeError: run() got an unexpected keyword argument 'comment'
None
```

Needless to say, this only happens for Python commands and not internal commands since those do not error at all. Also when do you try to run a command as `sublime.active_window().run_command( "reveal_in_side_bar" )` and it does not exist, Sublime Text does not throw an exception. This is to allow plugins or menu entries do not throw errors when they are not available.